# Correct sentence interjection usage

Tags: commas

The moose however proved to be more of a hazard than help in battle, as the moose’s natural instinct to hide overpowered their training to stay.

Or

The moose however proved to be more of a hazard than help in battle, as the moose’s natural instinct to hide, overpowered their training to stay.

Edit: My reasoning for going with example two, is that, the first time reading this sentence, I read "overpowered" as an adjective. I was expecting the sentence to read something along the lines of "... hide overpowered feelings of guilt" It led me to rereading the sentence a couple times. In my opinion, the comma clarifies the intent of overpowered to be read as a verb.

Comment: Generally, you don't separate your subject from your verb with a comma.

Comment: I would go with the first one, only with "however" encommatized.  And perhaps change "as" to "since".

Comment: And one could argue that the plurality of "moose's" should somehow be made to match "their".

Comment: as @deadrat mentioned, don't separate your subject from the verb. The subject is "The moose's natural instinct to hide" and the verb is "overpowered". It might also help to use a different verb that can't be seen as an adjective, such as "eclipsed" or "overshadowed" or "overtook" or "was [adjective] than"

Comment: I read the second half of your first sentence without a hitch, although on the first half I needed commas before and after "however" (as Hotlicks already pointed out).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use the first sentence.

A comma is used to separate independent clauses, among other things. "as the moose’s natural instinct to hide" is not an independent clause because it lacks a verb. "Overpowered" **is** your verb, so don't separate it from the subject with a comma.

> My reasoning for going with example two, is that, the first time reading this sentence, I read "overpowered" as an adjective.

If you feel this way, I would suggest using a different verb or sentence structure. Use verbs that are not common adjectives like "overpowered". These words can be used that way, but they are not as common and might not trigger that part in your brain that causes you to think of "overpowered" as only an adjective.

Try some of these:

- Eclipsed
- Overshadowed
- Overtook
- Was [comparative phrase] than (ex: Was stronger than, was more powerful than)

Answer (score 1):

Go with the first sentence.  Too many commas in the second.

Battle-Moose?  With steel blades in the tips of their antlers?  They would be awesome in battle if you could get them to attack, but contrary to the natural instinct of a prey animal.  This would be some kind of historical science fiction I presume. Well then anything goes?